# How would you search a database full of posts and return only ones that match?

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have a database full of items that are for sale. For example, a chainsaw, a TV, a lawnmower, etc.

If a user searches for "lawn supplies", everything related to lawn supplies should be presented to the user. In this case, items that are lawnmowers or edgers should be retrieved from the database.

How would I go about retrieving this information in the most efficient way possible? I am developing an iOS app and using Firebase for my database.

Comment: Can you present any code that you have tried for this. ?

Comment: You could simply have a child node 'type' with values of 'lawn supplies' or 'kitchen gadgets' or 'jewelry'. The user selects a type and then all of the items within that category are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use firestore `arraycontains` it will be helpful. Store words in array like `['lawn supplies','lawnmover']` related to that product and search

```
collection('arraycontains','lawn suplies')
    .limit(1)
    .getDocuments()
    .then()
    .catch() => List<SnapshotDocument> or [doc];
```

Comment: This is on track but I think the OP is using the Realtime Database so this would not apply. Also, we are Swifting on this question.